# Calculate Number of Tweets per Day

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to write a function which calculates the number of tweets that were posted per day.

Function Specifications:

It should take a pandas dataframe as input. It should return a new dataframe, grouped by day, with the number of tweets for that day. The index of the new dataframe should be named Date, and the column of the new dataframe should be 'Tweets', corresponding to the date and number of tweets, respectively.
The date should be formated as yyyy-mm-dd, and should be a datetime object. Hint: look up pd.to_datetime to see how to do this.

I tried this code out but it gives an error. I am also struggling to find a pd.to_datetime function that will work for this?

```
def number_of_tweets_per_day(df):
    """
    This function calculates the number of tweets that were posted per day.

    Parameters:
    -----------
    items: (dataframe), dataframe that contains the dates.

    Returns:
    --------
    num_of_tweets_per_day: (dataframe) contains dates and numbers of tweets per day.

    """

     df = pd.DataFrame([['Date'],['Tweets']
​
​
     df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
     df['Tweets'] = df['Tweets'].astype(str)

​
     df['Date'] = df['Date'] + '-' + df[Tweets]
​
​
     df.groupby(['Date'])['Tweets'].count()

     return
​
```

Comment: Your code have syntax error, please fix it. Also you need to share sample of your input df for others to understand.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example - could you provide example input, output and the error you are recieving?

Comment: _I tried this code out but it gives an error._ What error?  _I am also struggling to find a pd.to_datetime function that will work for this?_ What do you mean? `pandas.to_datetime()` **is** a function.

Comment: this is the error i had received. File "<ipython-input-239-ac45702a0754>", line 19
    df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: this is the code i tried:                                                                                                      
 df = pd.DataFrame([['Date'],['Tweets']


     df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str)
     df['Tweets'] = df['Tweets'].astype(str)
    

    df['Date'] = df['Date'] + '-' + df['Tweets']


    df.groupby(['Date'])(['Tweets']).count()
    
    return

Comment: All that information should be in your post, comments are difficult to read and much more prone to being deleted.